# How to debug event listener in background.js in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

What's the best way to test the code of **an event listener** in background.js in a Chrome extension with no UI?

Let's say I have the following background.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(request => {
    console.log(request);
});
```

I now want to debug different kinds of messages (e.g. `chrome.runtime.sendMessage('someMessage')`) and see the `console.log` be executed. I've tried using Chrome's DevTools for the background page and trying to `sendMessage` form the console but the `console.log` line is not getting hit.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(emphasis mine)

> I've tried using Chrome's DevTools ***for the background page*** and trying to `sendMessage` form the console but the `console.log` line is not getting hit.

A message sent in an extension page using `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` is *not* fired as an event in the same page. This is to prevent outgoing messages to be needlessly handled by the sender.

You'll need to create another page and testing from there.

It can be as minimal as a *blank* HTML file "test.html" you just open with `chrome-extension://<your-extension-id>/test.html` in a tab and then use the console from there.

Or, you can test from a content script (it's allowed to use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`), but be mindful of the context selected at the top of the console (normally reads "top" for the page's main frame).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was it. I created a `test.html`. Then ran `chrome.runtime.sendMessage('someMessage')` from that page's console. My background.js's event listener is now getting called.